# Insert cookie values with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, pdo

Hi I try to insert some cookie values with pdo into a Innodb on mysql. The page before set a cookie with the userid. Now the problem is that no values become added in the database. I think that the syntax at `WHERE id = $userid` is wrong or the query syntax. I get no error although I have `catch(PDOException $e)`. How should I write it?

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=searchfood", $user, $password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    // prepare your query
    $query = 'UPDATE users SET longitude=?, latitude=? WHERE id =?';

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);      
    // bind variables
    $stmt->execute(array($_COOKIE['longitude'], $_COOKIE['latitude'], $userid));
    // pull last insert id
    $new = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 




}
```

Comment: you're probably looking for INSERT OR REPLACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem here is that `INSERT` query inserts **NEW** data to a table.
If you want to update existing record - use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `table` SET field_name = "value" WHERE id = ID
```

Second problem is mixing placeholders for variables, you should use either `?` or `:name` in your queries (and **never** both) and bind variables accordingly.